# Is there a way that could display a panel from another form to the main form?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I would like to apologize in advance if I could not explain this problem clearer as I am not really good at explaining.

For  example, I have 3 forms. We'll call it frmMain, frm1, and frm2. `frm1` and `frm2` already has it's designs and codes, the objects are also in the panel. `frmMain`'s job, depending on the user's actions, is to display either `frm1` or `frm2` inside the `frmMain` depending on what the user clicks, either the button1 that will show frm1 or the button2 that will show the frm2.

I am aware of displaying a form to another form inside a panel with this code,

For example:

> PanelDisplay.Controls.Clear()
> frm1.TopLevel = False
> PanelDisplay.Controls.Add(frm1)
> frm1.Show()

I tried the codes above if it can display the panel, not the whole form. But it did not work.

Is there a way I could show panels from other forms to the main form without displaying the whole form? Just the panel and objects inside it.

Comment: that looks like you need to lookup mdi programming

Comment: Are you 100% sure frm1/frm2 should actually be forms?  Wondering if maybe a TabPage control rather than PanelDisplay? or maybe a little more advanced UserControls based on Panels?

Answer (score 0):

Method one:
Public Class Form2

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form3.TopLevel = False
        Form3.TopMost = True
        Form1.Panel1.Controls.Add(Form3)
        Form3.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Method
Place one panel on top of another,

Or even if you place them next to each other, you can use the click event of the panel itself to hide the panel and show another panel?
'enable menu CD Enable to start timer and to set the countdown starting & display the result.

```
 Private Sub mnuCDEnable_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuCDEnable.Click 
        tmrCDAlarm.Start() 
        mnuCDEnable.Checked = True 
        Panel2.Visible = True 
        niAlarm.Visible = True 
        mnuDisable.Checked = True 
        mnuEnable.Checked = False 
 
        'check mark the disable menu for the Alarm 
        If mnuCDEnable.Checked = True Then 
            mnuDisable.Checked = True 
        End If 
 
        'check to see which notifyicon is checked in the system tray.  
        If niAlarm.Visible = True Then 
            niRunning.Visible = False 
        End If 
 
        'check to see if panel2 is visible if so then make panel1 not visible. 
        If Panel2.Visible = True Then 
            Panel1.Visible = False 
        End If 
 
        'make sure that CD Enabled is unchecked and CD Disable is Checked. 
        If mnuCDEnable.Checked = True Then 
            mnuCDDisable.Checked = False 
        End If 
 
        'start the countdown using DateTimePicker1 as the alarm setting  
        If DateTime.Now > DateTimePicker1.Value Then Exit Sub 
        lblDays.Text = "T-minus ... " 
        lblDays.BackColor = Color.Empty 
        Alarm = DateTimePicker1.Value 
        Timer1.Start() 
    End Sub
```

This is the link of method two:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/13a67d64-e339-4edc-a2f2-c25ff644884f/panels-within-vbnet?forum=vblanguage